# How to merge multiple rows by a given condition and sum?

Tags: r

I have long format data with ID, time and state columns. I would like some states to be merged within ID by s_2 and s_3 and the time column to be summed. Let's say I have data:

```
ID state time
1 s_1 4
1 s_2 6
1 s_3 7
2 s_1 2
2 s_2 12
2 s_3 5
2 s_4 4
3 s_1 10
3 s_2 2
3 s_3 3
```

that I'd like to convert into:

```
ID state time
1 s_1 4
1 s_2+ 13
2 s_1 2
2 s_2+ 17
2 s_4 4
3 s_1 10
3 s_2+ 5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the label of `state` values and then group by sum.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, state = replace(state, state %in% c('s_2', 's_3'), 's_2+')) %>%
  summarise(time = sum(time))

#    ID state  time
#  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     1 s_1       4
#2     1 s_2+     13
#3     2 s_1       2
#4     2 s_2+     17
#5     2 s_4       4
#6     3 s_1      10
#7     3 s_2+      5
```

Or in base R :

```
aggregate(time~ID + state, transform(df,
          state = replace(state, state %in% c('s_2', 's_3'), 's_2+')), sum)
```

---

If there are many such groups that you want to collapse perhaps `forcats::fct_collapse` would be helpful.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, state = forcats::fct_collapse(state, `s2+` = c('s_2', 's_3'))) %>%
  summarise(time = sum(time))
```

Comment: Thank you. If there's any clean possibility if I'd like to use more conditions for different states? Or I should just go for a loop?

Comment: You can use `forcats::fct_collapse` where you can collapse number of groups into one. The syntax is something like this `forcats::fct_collapse(state, \`new_group1\` = c('old_group1', 'old_group2'), \`new_group2\` = c('old_group3', 'old_group4'))`. Also see updated answer to see how to use that for your example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df)

df <- df[,`:=`(
  state = case_when(
    state %in% c('s_1', 's_2') ~ "s_2+",
    TRUE ~ state
  ))
]

df <- df[, .(time = sum(time)), by = .(id, state)]
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm not familiar with data.table but it seems like it's about time for me to do it :)

Comment: Yes data.table is really worth being checked out. It is my favorite tool for handling tabular data. :) Good luck